# degree of extension of Q with primitive roots of unity

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, primitive-roots

**Question**

Show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n)/2$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

**Attempt**

Let $\sigma: z\mapsto \bar{z}$,$\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^{-1}$.Since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^{-1})$ we have $\sigma\in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$.

It is $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(n)$, and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^{<\sigma>}]=|<\sigma>|=2$.

I have o show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^{<\sigma>}=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$

Obviously $\sigma(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}) \subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^{<\sigma>}$

*Is this correct so far? How could I show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}) \supset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^{<\sigma>}$?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $n\ge 3$. Then $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ embeds in $\Bbb R$
but $L=\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ doesn't. Therefore $L\ne K$.
Also $\zeta$ is a zero of $X^2-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})X+1=0$ so that $|L:K|\le2$. Therefore $|L:K|=2$. But $|L:\Bbb Q|=\phi(n)$, etc.

Of course $\sigma$ acts as complex conjugation on $L$, so its
fixed field is $L\cap\Bbb R=K$.

Comment: So if I understand what you say is that my final question is obvious since $\sigma$ acts as complex conjugation on $L$?

Comment: Well, the two fields you write down both have codegree $2$ in $L$... @giannispapav

Comment: Now I see! Thanks once again @ Lord Shark the Unknown